# Issue with compiling a function which returns string &

Tags: c++, string, protocol-buffers

A C++ function is as below: This is a auto generated code from Google Protocol Buffers. This is for a variable string NodeId in .proto file.

```
inline const ::std::string& TestClass::nodeId() const {
  return *nodeId_;
```

The above function is called as below

```
const std::string& NodeId = TestClass.Testconfig().nodeId;
```

When I compile this file, i get below error.

```
prgms# g++ test.cpp
test.cpp:96:56: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’
```

Can some body point me, what is wrong here  and how to fix this particular error ?

Comment: What type is `nodeId_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call the function:

```
const std::string& NodeId = TestClass.Testconfig().nodeId();
                                                         ^^
```

Comment: Super Answer @Super Fast rate. I missed this for quite a long time. I really appreciate.